# Google Play Consoleで検索ワードを設定する方法

Tags: android, google-play, 検索, google-play-console

お世話になります。

Google PlayでのAndroidアプリリリースが初めてで、初歩的な質問をさせて頂きます。
「Google Play Console」でユーザーにアプリを見つけて貰う為に、検索のキーワードを設定するのかと思っていますが、どこで設定するのでしょうか。

以下のサイトを拝見した所、明確な検索ワードというよりは、タイトルなどで検索されるような記述が御座います。
App Storeのような検索キーワードの設定はないのでしょうか。
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=ja

初歩的な質問でお手数をお掛け致しますが、ご回答頂けますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答付きませんね。

自分がアプリをリリースした時にも検索キーワードの設定はありませんでした。
ので、無いと思います。

コンソールでリリースしたアプリの「名称」や「アプリの説明」の内容が検索にかかるようになっているようです。
リリース直後は検索にかかりませんが、大昔の経験では1時間～数日で検索にかかるようになります。
例えば自分がリリースしたアプリ名は「BoatNAVI」ですが、それとはやや異なる検索キーワード「プレイ ストア ボートナビ」で検索にかかります。

Comment: ご回答有難う御座います。 おっしゃる通り、名称や説明が検索ワードになっていそうです。 また過去のご経験も参考にさせて頂きます！